# Is there a better way to deal with default true?

Tags: javascript

First I tried this:

```
var coolFunc = function(options) {
  var minNum = options.minNum || true,
  // rest of the function
}
```

But that can never result in false as the value for the minNum var.

So now I am doing this:

```
var coolFunc = function(options) { 
  var minNum = options.minNum;
  if (minNum === undefined) minNum = true;
  // rest of the function
}
```

Is there a more standard way of doing this?

Comment: No, that's the right way.

Comment: Depends on the possible values, for example, if it can be null, this won't work and you would instead want `minNum = typeof options.minNum == "undefined" ? true : options.minNum` - as the shorthand is just doing falsy/truthy checks

Comment: dystroy is correct, it's the right way.  However, you can condense it slightly: `var minNum = options.minNum===undefined ? true : options.minNum;`

Comment: @EthanBrown Unless a crazy programmer set a variable called `undefined` to *true*.

Comment: @ComFreek That's not possible any more. And I guess those crazy programmers were fired too.

Comment: @ComFreek: yes, but then you have bigger problems.  Also, if that were the case, the OP's solution wouldn't work either.  I was just offering a slightly more compact formulation.

Comment: @dystroy Why isn't that possible anymore? I've just tested it: http://jsfiddle.net/2mvwt/1/ (latest IE and Chrome) /@Ethan: Yes, of course :)

Comment: @dystroy: That's implementation-dependent.  The JavaScript specification itself, unfortunately, allows for this possibility.  I just checked and the Google V8 engine doesn't allow for this anymore, but who knows what other engines will allow....

Comment: @ComFreek What isn't possible is to change `window.undefined` (see http://jsfiddle.net/2mvwt/1/). Yes, you can shadow it, you're right, but it's usually easier to spot because it's your scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the right way.

A common variant is

```
var coolFunc = function(options) { 
  var minNum = "minNum" in options ? options.minNum : true;
  // rest of the function
}
```

Personally I sometimes use a utility function:

```
function opt(options, key, defaultValue) {
    if (options && key in options) return options[key];
    return defaultValue;
};
```

so that my functions are like this:

```
var coolFunc = function(options) { 
  var minNum = opt(options, "minNum", true);
  // rest of the function
}
```

A small advantage is that it also checks that `options` isn't `undefined`.

but it's not a big gain, especially when you don't expect falsish values, so most often I don't care.

Answer (score 0):

This variant might be more straight forward than the ternary suggestions:

`var minNum = (typeof options.minNum !== 'boolean') || options.minNum;`

or

`var minNum = (! "minNum" in options) || options.minNum;`